# What is causing RedisTimeoutException in Azure Redis cache?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I have an Azure App Service, running 2 instances, that makes use of a shared Azure Redis Cache. *Most* of the time, everything is fine. But some days, I see `RedisTimeoutException` errors in my App Service logs. Typically, there is a timeout on a Write (SETEX) immediately followed by ~10 more timeouts which are a mix of Reads and Writes (other operations that were queued up behind the one that timed-out, I think).

Example:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response 
(outbound=0KiB, inbound=1KiB, 5984ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=SETEX, next: GET <Key_name>,
inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 14, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, 
serverEndpoint: <Azure_Redis_instance>, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: <App_service_instance>, 
IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.1.28.64774
(Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

I have followed the URL in their exception message and read through their explanation of possible timeout causes, but I don't believe any of these are the cause. [This subheading](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts#was-there-a-big-request-preceding-several-small-requests-to-the-redis-that-timed-out) caught my attention because I do see `qs: 14` in my exception above, but we're not using any commands that would be long-running. We only set/get individual cache entries using their key.

I've used Azure Portal > App Service > Metrics blade to look at the App Service during the time that these errors were appearing, and I don't see any spikes in CPU time, memory working set or connections (on either instance of the App Service).  I also checked the Redis Cache instance, and didn't see any spikes in memory or CPU usage.

I'm not sure what to look into next. Eg:

1. Would you try their suggestion to use *a pool of ConnectionMultiplexer objects* to avoid operations queueing up behind a slow operation? (I'd rather find out why it's slow)
2. Is there another key performance metric that I'm overlooking?
3. I didn't see an explanation for `mc: 1/1/0`, what does that mean?

Comment: When checking CPU usage on any system, you generally want to use Max CPU, not average.  Not sure which you looked at, but average can hide short lived spikes in CPU.  The fact that your busy worker thread count == Min thread count means that you could be running into [this threadpool problem](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md).